# Porting WinJs related code to Mac (iPad)

Tags: jquery, macos, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I was invoking an HTML page with the following command in my Windows Store App:

```html
<div id="random" 
     data-win-control="WinJs.UI.HtmlControl" 
     data-win-options="{uri:'/random.html'}">
</div>
```

I then call `.hide()` and `.show()`.

I am now porting this for iPad. Could anyone suggest, what to change minimum code and use the same html file. Is jQuery needed here? How to incorporate that here?

Comment: this HTML control is going to be unique to WinJS, does Objective C have a control that will render HTML?  Not sure where you would fit jQuery in here?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a framework that allows you to write HTML/JavaScript for the iPad (like PhoneGap or something). IN that case you certainly could use jQuery in your iOS project. It's a bit easier for this case than using raw JavaScript. The equivalent of the HtmlControl is just a jQuery `.append()`, and you can use `.hide()` and `.show()` just the same. Keep in mind that if you're trying to maintain code between the two projects, you may want to use the same technique (using jQuery) in both.

Answer (score 1):

If you format your options just a little differently, you can use jQuery to do this rather trivially:

```html
<div data-win-control="WinJs.UI.HtmlControl" 
     data-win-options='{"uri":"page1.html"}'></div>
<div data-win-control="WinJs.UI.HtmlControl" 
     data-win-options='{"uri":"page2.html"}'></div>
<script>
  var options;
  $("[data-win-control]").each(function () {
    options = $.parseJSON($(this).attr("data-win-options"));
    $(this).load( options.uri );
  });
</script>
```

Just understand that this is only superficially similar to a [`WinJS.UI.HtmlControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700625.aspx), and doesn't come anywhere near a full implementation.